# next.js inject component into DOM element outside of pages scope

Tags: reactjs, next.js, blogs, static-site-generation

I'm building a blog using next.js and on my article pages I'd like to add some article metadata to the (vertical) navbar.

I'm new to React and Next.js, and the lack of googleable solutions suggests I'm looking at this problem the wrong way, but here goes..

Each blog post is rendered using a page with a dynamic route `pages/blog/page/[...slug].js`. The navbar is defined outside of this page file: `_app.js` imports a `LayoutWrapper` component, and this component builds the navbar.

How can I add DOM elements to the navbar created in `_app.js` from within `[...slug].js`?

I *think* its something to do with `useRef()`, but I'm not sure.

Comment: Why don't you render necessary component wherever needed?

Comment: I need to render it from the [...slug].js page because I need to access the article metadata (date published, author, etc), but I dont want to render the navbar from the article page. I want to "inject" dom elements into the navbar.

Comment: You don't do DOM manipulations in React (it is intended to do whatever is required for you). React components are meant to implement **re-usable** pieces of UI. So, if you need the same UI element on multiple pages, you define it in /components directory and import where required. If you need to feed some globally accessible data to that component, use React Context or Redux to manage shared state.